# Cost of creating dbcontext per web request on ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Unit of work and Repository pattern along with EF6  in my asp.net web application. DbContext object is getting created and destroyed on every request.

I am thinking that it is costly creating the new dbcontext on every request(I have not done any performance bench marking).

Is this cost of creating DbContext on every request  can be ignored ? Does anybody done some bench marking?

Comment: If its already an issue then take some measurements (because they will be specific to your code) and correct any burning problems, but if its not actually causing any performance issues with your app (i.e. it works quickly enough) then you wouldn't you be better off spending that time adding any missing functionality or fixing defects rather than worrying about pre-optimizing something that may not ever be an issue? Just a thought.

Answer (score 9):

Creating a new context is ridiculously cheap, on the order of about 137 ticks on average (0.0000137 seconds) in my application.

Hanging onto a context, on the other hand, can be incredibly expensive, so dispose of it often.

The more objects you query, the more entities end up being tracked in the context.  Since entities are POCOS, entity framework has absolutely no way of knowing which ones you've modified except to examine every single one of them in the context and mark it accordingly.

Sure, once they're marked, it will only make database calls for the ones that need updated, but it's *determining which ones need updated* that is expensive when there are lots of entities being tracked, because it has to check all the POCOS against known values to see if they've changed.

This change tracking when calling save changes is so expensive, that if you're just reading and updating one record at a time, you're better off disposing of the context after each record and creating a new one.  The alternative is hanging onto the context, such that every record you read results in a new entity in the context, and every time you call save changes it's slower by one entity.

And yes, it really is slower.  If you're updating 10,000 entities for example, loading one at a time into the same context, the first save will only take about 30 ticks, but every subsequent one will take longer to the point where the last one will take over 30,000 ticks.  In contrast, creating a new context each time will result in a consistent 30 ticks per update.  In the end, because of the cumulative slow-down of hanging onto the context and all the tracked entities, disposing of and recreating the context before each commit ends up taking only 20% as long (1/5 the total time)!

That's why you should really only call save changes once on a context, ever, then dispose of it.  If you're calling save changes more than once with a lot of entities in the context, you may not be using it correctly.  The exceptional case, obviously, is when you're doing something transactional.

If you need to perform some transactional operation, then you need to manually open your own SqlConnection and either begin a transaction on it, or you need to open it within a TransactionScope.  Then, you can create your DbContext by passing it that same open connection.   You can do that over and over, disposing of the DbContext object each time while leaving the connection open.  Usually, DbContext handles opening and closing the context for you, but if you pass it an open connection, it won't try to close it automatically.

That way, you treat the DbContext as just a helper for tracking object changes on an open connection.  You create and destroy it as many times as you like on the same connection, where you can run your transaction.  It's very important to understand what's going on under the hood.

Comment: `Creating a new context is ridiculously cheap, hanging onto a context, on the other hand, can be incredibly expensive` - this is the key point, and nicely explained, thank you

Answer (score 5):

Entity Framework is not thread safe, meaning, you cannot use a context across more than one thread.  IIS uses a thread for each request sent to the server.  Given this, you have to have a context per request.  Else, you run a major risks of unexplained and seemingly random exceptions and potentially incorrect data being saved to the database.

Lastly, the context creation is not that expensive of an operation.  If you are experiencing a slow application experience (not on first start, but after using the site), your issue probably lies somewhere else.